# High number of new Threads (10k's every 60 seconds) causing memory issues

Tags: ruby, multithreading, server

I have a Ruby app which fetches recent messages for every user every 60 seconds. As the messages are hosted on a remote API, this is the most practical way to do this for now:

```
while true
  fetch_recent_messages do |result|
    # Handle result
  end

  sleep 60
end

def fetch_recent_messages()
  Thread.new do
    sleep_duration = 60 / @fetch_users.count

    for fetch_user in @fetch_users
      Thread.new do
        @api_manager.fetch_recent_messages_for_user(fetch_user)
        yield result
      end

      sleep sleep_duration
    end
  end
end
```

1. `fetch_recent_messages()` is called every 60 seconds.
2. `@fetch_users` is looped through, sleeping an appropriate amount of time on each iteration so that the function takes around 60 seconds to call `fetch_recent_messages_for_user()` across all users. This helps to spread the network and CPU load.
3. an iteration of the `@fetch_users` loop initialises a new thread, performs the API call on this thread, and then yields back to `while` loop with the result.

The crux of this is that a new thread is initialised for every API request, in order to allow them to occur asynchronously from each other. There may be a high volume of users, say 10k, so it's important that the fetch message requests for all users are able to be processed within the same 60 seconds. This is fine for CPU/memory usage on my server.

I noticed that the memory usage for this app was spontaneously jumping up or down for significant periods of time, and haven't been able to link it to any particular behaviour. This could occur after running at 15% CPU usage for 24 hours or longer - it'd suddenly jump to 30%, and then a while later maybe up to 40% or down again. There doesn't seem to be a pattern to it. I ended up commenting out everything except from the creation of new threads to watch the performance, and it would seem that that's causing the memory issues.

I wonder if there's issues in Ruby with maintaining a high volume of threads, and whether I should be handling them differently, or perhaps doing this task differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most languages that implement threads, there is a surprisingly low threshold (I don't know, hundreds maybe, depending on many things) beyond which additional threads are problematic. (Erlang / Elixir processes are a dramatic exception.)

I'd suggest peering into your system at intervals to see how many threads are active at any one time.

In addition, for uses like this where many, many threads are used over the lifetime of the program, *thread pools* are normally used to drastically reduce the amount of overhead incurred in the creation and destruction of threads. Using these pools, you have a fixed number of threads that are made available for reuse once their job has completed.

Here is a link to the documentation for one implementation of thread pools in Ruby: https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/blob/master/doc/thread_pools.md.